# React: dynamic rendering of a component based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Parent`(blue box with three buttons) and a `Child`(red box that shows content) component, that render some text based on the `Child`'s state. Basically, the rendered view is this:

[image]

The `Child` component:

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tab: this.props.tab
    }
  }
  render() {
    let text;

    if (this.props.tab === '1') {
      text = <div>text 1 </div>
    } else if (this.props.tab === '2') { 
      text = <div>text 2 </div>
    } else if (this.props.tab === '3') {
      text = <div>text 3 </div>
    }
  return (
    <div>
      {text}
    </div>
    );
  } 
}

export default Child;
```

The `Parent` component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tab: null
    }
    this.onOneClik = this.onOneClik.bind(this);
    this.onTwoClik = this.onTwoClik.bind(this);
    this.onThreeClick = this.onThreeClick.bind(this);
  }
  onOneClik(e) {
    this.setState({ tab: '1' });
  }
  onTwoClik(e) {
    this.setState({ tab: '2' });
  }
  onThreeClick(e) {
    this.setState({ tab: '3' });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onOneClik}>1</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onTwoClik}>2</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onThreeClik}>3</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Child tab={this.state.tab} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is that I need to re-render the Child when the button is clicked, but the Child shows only the content of the button which was clicked first, even though the state of the Parent updates itself when different buttons are clicked.

What would be the way to dynamically render the Child without involving Links? I guess redux could help, but I'm not sure on how to wrap redux around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component will be re-rendered when its `state` or `props` changes. Instead of storing the initial `tab` prop in the state of the `Child` component, you can use the prop directly instead (you also have a few typos that are fixed below).

**Example**

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let text;

    if (this.props.tab === "1") {
      text = <div> text 1 </div>;
    } else if (this.props.tab === "2") {
      text = <div> text 2 </div>;
    } else if (this.props.tab === "3") {
      text = <div> text 3 </div>;
    }

    return <div>{text}</div>;
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tab: null
  };

  onOneClick = e => {
    this.setState({ tab: "1" });
  };
  onTwoClick = e => {
    this.setState({ tab: "2" });
  };
  onThreeClick = e => {
    this.setState({ tab: "3" });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onOneClick}>
          1
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onTwoClick}>
          2
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onThreeClick}>
          3
        </button>
        <Child tab={this.state.tab} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @Ruham You're welcome! Yeah, it's tempting to put props in state, but most of the time you really don't have to.

Comment: What are the advantages of using http://unpkg.com ?